# Do sub-stochastic matrices reduce the 1-norm of vectors?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, stochastic-processes, normed-spaces

It is well-known that "stochastic matrices preserve the 1-norm of vectors, $||\mathbf{A}\vec{v}||_1=||\vec{v}||_1$". I am thus wondering whether sub-stochastic matrices (a square matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ with nonnegative entries so that every row adds up to *at most* 1) *reduce* instead the 1-norm of a vector, $||\mathbf{Q}\vec{v}||_1\leq ||\vec{v}||_1$...is there a proof of this, and under which conditions?
This should be a well-known fact (or at least easy to disprove), but I have so far failed. Many thanks.

Comment: Do you require that $v$ has non-negative entries?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ have non-negative entries.

Observe,
$$
Qv
=
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_{1,1}v_1 + Q_{1,2}v_2 + \cdots Q_{1,n}v_n \\
Q_{2,1}v_1 + Q_{2,2}v_2 + \cdots Q_{2,n}v_n \\
\vdots \\
Q_{n,1}v_1 + Q_{n,2}v_2 + \cdots Q_{n,n}v_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then, using the assumption that $Q_{i,j} v_j \geq 0$,
$$
\| Qv \|_1
= \sum_{i} \left| \sum_j Q_{i,j} v_j \right|
= \sum_{i} \sum_j Q_{i,j} v_j 
= \sum_j \left[ v_j \sum_{i}  Q_{i,j} \right]
$$
Therefore, if the *columns* of $Q$ sum to 1, then $\| Q v \|_1 = \|v\|_1$.

If the columns of $Q$ sum to something less than 1 (what you're asking about), what does this tell you about how this new sum compares to the sum if the columns of $Q$ summed to 1?